# Is it in Pandas possible to assign a row reference to a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reference, iterator

I need to do a calculation of row values and value changes to a data frame while using (for example) `df.at[idx,'var1']=1`

Since I need to do a lot of changes to various variables I have the following question.
Is it possible to provide a referencing such as `r=df.at[idx,:]` so I can do changes to the code with less typing such as `r("var1")=1, r("var2")=2`, etc?

Comment: if _less typing_ is the final goal, you can always wrap whatever logic in a function and just call it (though `df.at[a,b] = 1` doesnt' look like a lot of code to me), e.g. `r = lambda idx: df.at[idx, :]` and `r('var1')` or something in that direction

Comment: sometimes *less typing* you can get by putting data on list and using `for`-loop to run code with these data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Assuming you already have your dataframe defined 
# as df and your index defined as idx

# create function
def r(var=None, value=None, df=df):
    df.at[idx,var]=value

# call function with var and value
# you could do this with a list of tuples
list1 = list(range(1,10))
list2 = list(range(11,20))
for x, y in list(list1, list2):
    r(var=x, value=y)
```

This is not a particularly fast way of doing this, but it's a valid way of doing this. It would likely be more typing, but faster, to generate a    mask     of your dataframe and repopulate data based on that mask.

Comment: I'd recommend against assigning mutable variables (such as `df`) as default arguments in functions ;)